# What type of glasses is Tsukishima wearing?

Tags: haikyuu

All it says is that they're prescription sports glasses. Are they similar to any brand or particular model? Below is a pretty zoomed-in panel of the glasses, although there may be more descriptive images online.

[image]

Comment: do you have any reason to think that these should be branded?

Comment: @ton.yeung no, I'm just looking for a possible similar model.

Comment: where have you looked? brick and mortar? online?

Comment: Mostly online. I'd just like a link to a similar model.

Comment: Uhh.. i googled prescription sports glasses and the first two sites had things very similar to them. Try zennioptical or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tsukishima's seems to be a pretty common type of prescription sport glasses. It is easy to find some reasonable similar ones. See for example [here](http://www.eyekit.co/goggles/industrial-and-domestic-safety-goggles/bolle-safety-for-industrial-safety-goggles/bolle-prescription-safety-goggles-twister-black-for-industrial-safety-eyewear.html), [here](http://www.zennioptical.com/sports-glasses?view=all) and [here](http://www.uksportseyewear.co.uk/product.php/187/childrens-football-goggles).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is called a goggle. Mostly it is to protect from any kind of eye injuries in high contact sports. Also can be used for those who have bad sights. I use the same as Tsukishima has when I play basketball. I bought it online like 2 years ago.